# How to measure the physical size of a query of documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

I want to be able to measure the amount of data each of my users store. I have abstracted all the storage items to use STI so I only need to query from one table, I was hoping there was a way to measure the data size of all data with user_id=n.

Comment: Retrieve the count() for user_id=n and multiply it by avgObjSize ( which you can get from db.coll.stats() )

Comment: That is a pretty good idea on how to get the approximate size. Thanks this is a good quick solution